# объединить массивы php в один

Tags: php, массивы

Такой вопрос.
Есть переменная $myarr. Вывод print_r

```
Array
(
    [VALUE] => 2497
    [PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE] => В наличии
)
Array
(
    [VALUE] => 2482
    [PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE] => В наличии
)
```

Подскажите, каким образом привести к такому виду?

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2497
    [1] => 2482
)
```

Comment: [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) вам в помощь

Comment: Спасибо! попробовал, вот что получилось
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2497
            [1] => 2497
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => В наличии
            [1] => В наличии
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2482
            [1] => 2482
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => В наличии
            [1] => В наличии
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ прост: использовать [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$result = array_column($myarr, 'VALUE');
```

Comment: В итоге пусто
`Array
(
)
Array
(
)`

Comment: @baltimor значит ты привёл неправильный массив... потому что наглядный пример  https://onlinephp.io/c/6a540   показывает всё вполне нормально... и уж точно результат не должен показывать `Array ( ) Array ( )`,  потому что результатом будет **один массив**

Comment: В том то и дело, что это два отдельных массива. https://paste.ofcode.org/wfmYwK2QuNBF47TRsnye9S

Comment: Так они же у тебя лежат в отдельной переменной `$myarr`, то есть это массив с массивами. Или я не прав?

Comment: Вот код
https://paste.ofcode.org/36spjXHFESYJNpWU77bZQm6
В переменной $arResult['PROPERTIES']['ASSOCIATED']['VALUE'] хранятся ID 
Я пытаюсь отфильтровать эти ID с помощью свойства ['PROPERTY_STATUS_VALUE'] 
Если в наличии, то выводить этот ID если нет, то не выводить, или убрать из этого массива

Comment: Таким образом и надо описывать вопросы.......... потому что на текущий момент условия совсем поменялись и нужно совсем другое, не то,  что в вопросе написано и в котором ни разу не написано, что надо отфильтровать по статусу В наличии

Comment: А по итогу тебе нужен https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php